# Meaning of Screen size in Inch

Tags: screens, television

What does it mean that my laptop screen size is 15.4 Inch or IPad screen size is 9.7 inch? Is it the width, length, diameter or surface?

Is the concept the same for the TVs, Monitors, tablets and cell phones? Wide screens and ...? Are there some standard length to width ratios for them?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about consumer electronics

Comment: screens are measured on the diagonal. From corner to corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost always diagonal measurement, from corner to opposite corner. Sometimes, they will refer to xx-class size (e. g. 45 inch diagonal-class, meaning "almost that size".

Conventional screens are generally 4:3 width-to-height ratio. Wide screens are generally 16:9, occasionally 16:10 or other ratios.